# Importing Tables from Word to Excel by section

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I currently have excel VBA code that opens a form where I can select a Word document.  The code then can get one of 3 tables.  The last, second to last and third to last.  This worked because I can get the total table count and the 3 tables I needed were always the last ones in the documents.  Now, the users are allowed to add tables after the 3 I need so I need to add some code to ensure I am getting the ones I want.  This is where I have an issue.

My three tables are the only ones in document sections 10.1, 10.2 and 10.3.  I don't know how to tell which table by index number is in these document sections.  Is there a way I can find the table in Word document section 10.1?

My current code looks like:

```
Public Sub Get_TP_101(allbool As Boolean)
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim tableNo As Integer 'the table number the user selects
    Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
    Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
    Dim resultRow As Long
    Dim tableStart As Integer
    Dim tableTot As Integer ' the total number of tables in Document
    Dim Ret As Variant
    Dim sFullFileName As String
    Dim pagenum As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc*),*.doc*", , _
    "Browse for the Test Procedure containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

    With wdDoc
        tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
        If tableTot = 0 Then
            MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
            vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
        ElseIf tableTot > 1 Then
            'tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
            "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
            tableNo = tableTot - 2 '' get the third from last table by table index number
        End If

        resultRow = 1

        'For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
            With .tables(tableNo)
                'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
                For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                    For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                        Worksheets("TP_10_1").Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                    Next iCol
                    resultRow = resultRow + 1
                Next iRow
            End With
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        'Next tableStart
    End With

    wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ''Format
    Worksheets("TP_10_1").Range("A2:I5000").WrapText = True
    Worksheets("TP_10_1").Range("A2:I5000").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Worksheets("TP_10_1").Range("A2:I5000").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

    If allbool = False Then
        MsgBox ("Done import Table 10.1")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this - the function will return the first table it finds in the section number you provide.

NOTE: there must be at least one table in the section, otherwise it may pick up the next table it finds, which may be in a following section...

Only lightly tested, so you need to do some of your own testing!

```
Sub TestGettingTable()

    Dim tbl As Table
    Set tbl = GetATable(ThisDocument, "2.1")

    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
    End If

End Sub


Function GetATable(d As Word.Document, listNum As String)

    Dim p As Paragraph, rng As Object, tbl As Object

    For Each p In d.Paragraphs
        If p.Style = "Heading 2" And p.Range.ListFormat.ListType = _
                                         wdListOutlineNumbering Then

            If p.Range.ListFormat.ListString = listNum Then

                Set rng = p.Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=wdGoToNext)
                If rng.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                    Set tbl = rng.Tables(1)
                    Exit For
                End If

            End If 'matches number
        End If 'is Heading 2
    Next p

    Set GetATable = tbl

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response to your question.  I was waiting for an email to popup saying someone responded.  Must have missed it while trying to solve the issue.  I came up with a workaround by just cycling through the tables by the table index until I found the ones with header rows that matched the one I was looking for.  But I certainly going to try your method today.